# Random Sample ¿Random variables or realizations of the same random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A random sample is a collection of variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ that are independent and identically distributed. My question: Is a random sample made up of different random variables, or are they realizations of the same random variable? That is, different values ​​that the function takes for different elements of the sample space. For example, if the random variable is the weight of university students in the United States, then the random sample is made up of only a few students from that sample space after applying the function to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set up our model either way. Personally I like to think of a random variable as a measurement resulting from an experiment. In your example, I would consider $n$ different (independent) experiments consisting of measuring the weight of a random university student and each random variable will be associated with a single experiment. So the random sample will be made up of different random variables.